# If contact with darkspawn blood transmits the taint, why do people use bladed weapons instead of blunt weapons?

Tags: dragon-age

The *Dragon Age* wiki says that the [taint](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Taint) is spread by contact with darkspawn blood:

> The taint is a corruption spread by the darkspawn that ultimately makes the victim hear the call of the Old Gods. It can be transmitted through contact with darkspawn blood and fluids, or through objects imbued with the taint, such as eluvians. The contact does not automatically make one sick, but there is a great chance of it.

Additionally, the taint is lethal for virtually everyone.

However, *Dragon Age*, especially *Origins*, is famous for having characters get drenched in blood after a battle.

[image: Dragon Age: Origins blood splatters]

The blood splatters aren't just a gameplay thing; they happen in cutscenes too. For instance, the opening cinematic where Duncan, leader of the Grey Wardens, the front line against the darkspawn, uses a sword to fight one and becomes drenched in blood (and wipes his mouth with a bloody gauntlet…eww!)

Given that contact with darkspawn blood causes the taint, why do people so commonly use bladed weapons that draw blood and splatter it everywhere?

Sure, fighting with ranged weapons (or ranged magic) would be even more preferable so that there is zero chance of being exposed to blood, but sometimes you just have to fight in melee. Why not use blunt weapons, which cause internal bleeding and are far less likely to expose the fighter to blood, thus reducing their risk of becoming tainted?

Comment: If you try to kill a living being doesn't also blood flew forth if a blunt weapon is used? (at least in films)

Comment: @Thomas, blunt force trauma is likely to spill blood (and splatter it everywhere)if said force is sufficient to break the skin. However, it's not necessary to spill blood when killing using a blunt weapon and the odds of being covered in the stuff is lower than using (for instance) a sword. That being said, one would expect such a dire potential consequence leading to a greater use of ranged weapons.

Comment: @Thomas It's not impossible for blood to be drawn from a blunt weapon, but it's less likely. Blunt force trauma primarily causes internal bleeding and bruising (think black eyes and such). *Dungeons & Dragons* is a fantasy world where many clerics use blunt weapons because of religious restrictions against drawing blood, which I understand is based on some medieval restrictions for the same reason. In this case, I would think that not spilling blood would be more desirable for practical reasons of not becoming tainted.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins yepp it is way lower a risk with blunt force, and WAY WAY less with ranged (although in dragon age 1 they made use of the bows....imho they let loose of the dogs WAY too fast though but that could have been artistic interpretation there so to say because it looked cooler that way).  But yeah...ranged then blunt and only thne bladed....if it is just about getting infected. Although with how dangerous the tainted are.....killing them fast COULD outweigh the getting infected thing (thus bladed instead of blunt weapons)

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Absolutely ranged weapons (and ranged magic) would probably be more desirable in a world where being exposed to blood is bad. However, there are times where melee fighting is necessary, like in close quarters (Duncan had to fight melee in the opening cinematic). So in those cases, I'm wondering why they don't use blunt weapons.

Comment: @Thunderforge the only logical reason I can think of is because with blunt weapons it takes more force and possibly also more hits to make an enemy incapable of returning the blows......or outright killing him.

Comment: Duncan and other Grey Wardens are immune to taint because they've already been exposed to it and survived during their initiation. Since it's mostly Grey Wardens we see here, there's no extra point in using blunt weapons.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I recall that Grey Wardens still went crazy from the taint later in their life (and they usually end their lives by going to the Deep Roads and just taking out as many darkspawn as they could before then). I was always under the assumption that more exposure to darkspawn blood accelerated this, but I could be wrong there. Regardless, non-Grey Wardens still get splattered with darkspawn blood, as we see with Leliana in the picture. That just seems reckless to use weapons that would expose vulnerable companions to the taint.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Found in [this interview](http://swooping-is-bad.livejournal.com/1286233.html) with David Gaider, lead writer for *Origins* and most of the novels, where he says that Grey Wardens start turning more quickly during a Blight, partly because of how much interaction with the darkspawn they have, but he doesn't clarify whether that's because of proximity to darkspawn or exposure to their blood. It's possible the Wardens don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main danger is swallowing darkspawn blood; if you do that, you *Will* be infected. [Source: some of the Dragon Age novels; mainly in the context of what happens if dogs or griffins bite darkspawn. Normal blood spatter from combat seems to be a lower risk factor (Clawing darkspawn is apparently fine), though getting darkspawn blood in a cut seems to be another way of getting infected].

Also, remember that blights where the darkspawn invade the surface are very rare occurences.

Grey wardens are immune to being infected; the joining ritual basically infects them with a very slow acting version of the taint while protecting them from (or curing early stages of) the normal taint.  So Grey wardens can use edged weapons with no problems.

For normal people, remember that Blights are rare - so there's usually no reason to train with blunt weapons most of the time (and presumably there are reasons why, historically, edged weapons seem to be more popular - longer reach for one, with pikes and spears).  So when an invasion starts, people are going to defend themselves with the weapons they have, and are trained in - and for many, that's going to be edged weapons. Couple that with the apparent low risk from contact with darkspawn blood if you don't get it in an open wound or swallow it, and that probably explains it.